# Qt Designer: Why the border-radius dosen't work in QTableWidget?

Tags: pyqt5, qt-designer

I'm using QtDesigner and I want to get a radius in the corners of a tablewidget. I did this in many widget(QPushButton, Qlabel...) and it works. I don't know why this isn't working on tablewidget.
This is my stylesheet:

```
QTableWidget{
background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
border-radius:5px;
font: 6pt ;
}
```

Comment: You need to specify the border width/style.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand you. I want to get a circle corner in my table, I used the border-radius method in many widget like QPushButton, QLabel... and it works well, I don't know why it's not working at QtableWidget

Comment: It works fine for me on Linux. To get a visible border, the width/style must be specified (e.g. `border: 1px solid;`). Otherwise, the corners are rounded, but there's no border. If this doesn't work for you, you must be on a platform that has incomplete/buggy qt stylesheet support.